# How can I change the WordPress Custom Post & Categories to New Custom Post & Categories

Tags: sql, wordpress

In my database I have 2 custom post type and their category.

**Old Post Type and Category**

Post Type = real-estate
Category = re-category

**Mew Post Type and Category**

Post Type = real_estate
Category = real_estate_category

Now I want to convert all **old post type and their categories** to **new custom post type and their categories**.

So, using this code I can get all the old post type and can change the old post type to new post type **BUT** **how can I change the old post type's attached categories to new post type categories?**

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'everstrap_do_migration' );
function everstrap_do_migration() {
    // Convert their real-estate to real_estate post type
    if( $_REQUEST['action'] && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'convert_re_post_type' ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $old_custom_post_type = 'real-estate';
        $ne_custom_post_type = 'real_estate';

        // A sql query to return all real-esate post 
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = %s and post_status = 'publish'", $old_custom_post_type ), ARRAY_A );

        // Return null if we found no results
        if ( ! $results )
            return;

        foreach ( $result as $key => $value) {
            // Update query         
            $update = $wpdb->update(
                $wpdb->posts,
                array( 
                    'post_type' => $new_custom_post_type,
                ), 
                array(
                    'post_type' => $old_custom_post_type,
                ), 
                array( 
                    '%s',               
                ), 
                array( 
                    '%s' 
                ) 
            );

            if( $update ) {
                echo 'Updated post id ' . $value['ID'];
            } else {
                echo 'can\' update';
            }    
        }
        // echo '<pre>';
        //  print_r( $results );
        // echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new = "real_estate_category";
$old = "re-category";

$cat = get_terms( array (
    'taxonomy' => $old,
    'hide_empty' => false,
));

global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . "term_taxonomy";
foreach ($cat as $c) {          
    $wpdb->update($table, array("taxonomy" => $new), array("term_id" => $c->term_id), array("%s"));         
}
```